# How to position an element to a selected anchor without giving rendering each anchor's content for each anchor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items (anchors) and every time an element is selected, I want to render a component (a color picker) just under it:

```
import * as React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import "./styles.css";

interface DropDownProps {
  index: number;
}
const DropDown: React.FC<DropDownProps> = React.memo(({ index }) => (
  <div className="dropdown">dropdown for anchor {index}</div>
));

export default React.memo(() => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<null | number>(null);

  const handleSelect = React.useCallback(
    (index: number) => () => {
      setSelected(index);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={clsx("anchor", { selected: selected === index })}
            onClick={handleSelect(index)}
          >
            anchor {index} ↓{selected === index && <DropDown index={index} />}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
});
```

The problem is that the `Array.from` expands to:

```
<div className={clsx("anchor", { selected: selected === 0 })}>
  {'anchor 0 ↓'}
  {selected === 0 && <DropDown index={0} />}
</div>
<div className={clsx("anchor", { selected: selected === 1 })}>
  {'anchor 1 ↓'}
  {selected === 1 && <DropDown index={1} />}
</div>
<div className={clsx("anchor", { selected: selected === 2 })}>
  {'anchor 2 ↓'}
  {selected === 2 && <DropDown index={2} />}
</div>
```

I'd like the `DropDown` component to somehow be 'portaled' to whichever element is currently selected, instead of being conditionally rendered based on the value of `selected`. How can I do this?

[image: tender-margulis-cjil0b]

Comment: Are you concerned about performance?

Comment: That's a fair point, I'm actually not, but I wonder which method is more performant?

Comment: I made a bit of a hacky solution, that portals the dropdown to the selected element, that works. If that fits your needs and you are fine with this i can post it as an answer. here the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-worker-o1x3ws?file=/src/App.tsx 
the idea is to update the ref after the selection has changed (when the id of the element will be updated)

Comment: Hacky because of the forced update? Seems like a fine solution to me

Comment: yes it's one rerender per different selection extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the selected `div` an `id`, which we will use to portal the dropdown to. To do this we will `useRef` to retrieve and store the element with the id. Since the id will only be assigned in the rerender after the selection, we add an `useEffect` to update the ref after the selection changed, while using a dummy `useState` to force another update (since setting the value of a ref does not cause rerenders). Then the dropdown will appear below the correct item.

```
export default React.memo(() => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<null | number>(null);
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  const [_, forceUpdate] = React.useState(0);

  const handleSelect = React.useCallback(
    (index: number) => () => {
      setSelected(index);
    },
    []
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.getElementById("selected");
    forceUpdate((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, [selected]);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            id={selected === index ? "selected" : ""}
            className={clsx("anchor", { selected: selected === index })}
            onClick={handleSelect(index)}
          >
            anchor {index}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {selected !== null &&
        !!ref.current &&
        ReactDOM.createPortal(<DropDown index={selected} />, ref.current)}
    </div>
  );
});
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-worker-o1x3ws?file=/src/App.tsx)